# How to fetch all links and click those links one by one using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using Selenium WebDriver with java.

I am fetching all links from webpage and trying to click each link one by one. I am getting below  error:

> error org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
>   Command duration or timeout: 30.01 seconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
>   Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'

and here is my code :

```
public void getLinks()throws Exception{
    try {
        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        int linkcount = links.size(); 
         System.out.println(links.size()); 
          for (WebElement myElement : links){
         String link = myElement.getText(); 
         System.out.println(link);
         System.out.println(myElement);   
        if (link !=""){
             myElement.click();
             Thread.sleep(2000);
             System.out.println("third");
            }
            //Thread.sleep(5000);
          } 
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("error "+e);
        }
    }
```

actually,  it's displaying in output

> [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (ce0da229-f77b-4fb8-b017-df517845fa78)] -> tag name: a]

as link, I want to eliminate these form result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such a good idea to have following scenario :

```
for (WebElement element : webDriver.findElements(locator.getBy())){
  element.click();
}
```

Why? Because there is no guarantee that the `element.click();` will have no effect on other found elements, so the `DOM` may be changed, so hence the `StaleElementReferenceException`.

It is better to use the following scenario :

```
int numberOfElementsFound = getNumberOfElementsFound(locator);
for (int pos = 0; pos < numberOfElementsFound; pos++) {
  getElementWithIndex(locator, pos).click();
}
```

This is better because you will always take the `WebElement` refreshed, even the previous click had some effects on it.

EDIT : Example added

```
  public int getNumberOfElementsFound(By by) {
    return webDriver.findElements(by).size();
  }

  public WebElement getElementWithIndex(By by, int pos) {
    return webDriver.findElements(by).get(pos);
  }
```

Hope to be enough.

Comment: can pls give me one sample example of above scenario. It will really appreciable. thanks.

Comment: @loan I am still struggling, didn't get through. May be because I'm new to selenium driver. loop is running 4 times after that it sending following error  <blockquote>'error org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 30.05 seconds
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6 >

Comment: Well this is a different problem than StaleElementReferenceException. It means that you are trying to access an element which is not visibile, and most probably which is made visibile by another element. So first you have to identify which is this element, and then to make sure that it is visibile before to perform any actions on it. Or if is not mandatory, you can use .isDisplayed() method, to check if this element is proper, and then continue.

Comment: Perfect Loan, I added driver.navigate().back()

Answer (score 2):

Credit goes to "loan".

I am also getting "stale exception" so I used 'loan' answer and works perfectly. Just if anyone need to know how to click on each link from results page try this (java)

`clickAllHyperLinksByTagName("h3");` where "h3" tag contains hyperlink

```
 public static void clickAllHyperLinksByTagName(String tagName){
    int numberOfElementsFound = getNumberOfElementsFound(By.tagName(tagName));
    System.out.println(numberOfElementsFound);
    for (int pos = 0; pos < numberOfElementsFound; pos++) {
        getElementWithIndex(By.tagName(tagName), pos).click();
        driver.navigate().back();
    }
}

public static int getNumberOfElementsFound(By by) {
    return driver.findElements(by).size();
}

public static WebElement getElementWithIndex(By by, int pos) {
    return driver.findElements(by).get(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Then("^I will fetch the URL$")
public void i_will_fetch_the_url() throws Throwable {

```
    List<WebElement> jobLinks =driver.findElements(By.tagName("loc"));
    
    List<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    for (WebElement element : jobLinks) {
        texts.add(element.getText());
    }

    for(String text:texts) {

    System.out.println(text);
        Base.driver.get(text);
        
    }
```

Comment: Downvoting. Your answer is missing important parts.

Comment: please edit the answer to include clarifications (vs. doing so in a comment)

Answer (score 1):

```
    WebDriver _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    _driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.co.in/");
    List <WebElement> alllinks = _driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for(int i=0;i<alllinks.size();i++)
        System.out.println(alllinks.get(i).getText());

    for(int i=0;i<alllinks.size();i++){
        alllinks.get(i).click();
        _driver.navigate().back();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that will work, having navigated away won't you get a stale object exception? I think you have to look up all the links each time, take an object and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK using `WebDriver.get()` instead of `WebElement.click()` to test the links, an alternate approach is to save the `href` value of each found `WebElement` in a separate list. This way you avoid the `StaleElementReferenceException` because you're not trying to reuse subsequent `WebElement`s after navigating away with the first `WebElement.click()`.

Basic example:

```
List<String> hrefs = new ArrayList<String>();
List<WebElement> anchors = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for ( WebElement anchor : anchors ) {
    hrefs.add(anchor.getAttribute("href"));
}
for ( String href : hrefs ) {
    driver.get(href);           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//extract the link texts of each link element
        for (WebElement elements : linkElements) {
            linkTexts[i] = elements.getText();
            i++;
        }

        //test each link
        for (String t : linkTexts) {
            driver.findElement(By.linkText(t)).click();
            if (driver.getTitle().equals(notWorkingUrlTitle )) {
                System.out.println("\"" + t + "\""
                        + " is not working.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\"" + t + "\""
                        + " is working.");
            }
            driver.navigate().back();
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
```

For complete Explanation Read This [POST](http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/10/selenium-test-to-check-links-in-web.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
List <WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));                 
int linkCount=links.size();

System.out.println("Total number of page on the webpage:"+ linkCount);
String[] texts=new String[linkCount];
int t=0;
for (WebElement text:links){
  texts[t]=text.getText();//extract text from link and put in Array
  //System.out.println(texts[t]);
  t++;
}
for (String clicks:texts) {

  driver.findElement(By.linkText(clicks)).click();
  if (driver.getTitle().equals("notWorkingUrlTitle" )) {
    System.out.println("\"" + t + "\""
    + " is not working.");
  } else {
    System.out.println("\"" + t + "\""
                       + " is working.");
  }

  driver.navigate().back();
}

driver.quit();
```