# Clicking on the next list element using Webdriver selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a page with a list of 10 different elements links , I clicao an element , go to page specifies it, realize the operations that need to perform and then return to the list of elements .

After performing the operations , I need to return to the list of items and click the next element and not on the same element that clicked previously .

How do I click the next element of the list and not in LEMENT already clicked?

Obs .: I do not have access to the source code.

basic structure of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Page Test</h2>

    <div id="results-container"><ol id="results" class="search-results">

    <li class="mod result idx0 people hover" data-li-entity-id="354494011" data-li-position="0"> </li>

    </div>

    </br>


    <div id="results-container"><ol id="results" class="search-results">

        <li class="mod result idx0 people hover" data-li-entity-id="354494012" data-li-position="1"> </li>

    </div>
    </br>

    <div id="results-container"><ol id="results" class="search-results">

        <li class="mod result idx0 people hover" data-li-entity-id="354494022" data-li-position="2"> </li>

    </div>

</body>
</html>

    java.util.List<WebElement> links = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.linkText("element"));           
    System.out.println(links.size());
```

[image: Page]

Comment: Why can't you just start loop and call each element by it's index?

Comment: Because each one changes the page.

Comment: Sooooo...? What is the problem?:) You run `for` loop for each element in list that you get from `find_elements()` click on first link, do all your operations, then in next iteration you do all the same for next element and so on...

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13448091/954442. It has a solution that also avoids you hitting the inevitable StaleElementException.

Comment: @Andersson
I'm new to Selenium , you can give me an example of how to do this , please?

Comment: @AndrewRegan 
I did not understand the application of the link you gave me , I'll keep reading it to see if I understand .

I updated the question with the structure of the page you need .

Comment: @PauloSilva, I don't know `Java` syntax, so I can't provide you a solution or an example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.className("search-results"));
for( int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++)
{
    //The stop below is necessary to store all links in a list to access later.  
    links = driver.findElements(By.className("search-results")); 
    links.get(i).click();
    // Your code here
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the operations you need to perform are the same for all the pages you navigate to, you can use something like this:

```
List<WebElement> links = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.linkText("element"));           
for (WebElement link : links) 
{
    link.click();
    doWhateverOtherActions();
    driver.navigate().back();
    break();
}
```

If the actions on each page are different, you should consider identifying each link separately as a WebElement, and create methods for each to click on the link, do specific actions for that page and return to the initial page.

Comment: failed, to return to the page they click on the same link already clicked previously .