# How to return links on page and click on them

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am writing some e2e tests using protractor. The page links may change both name and number of links. What I am wanting to do have the page tell me the link names and number of links and then iterate over each link and click it.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="Transition in DirectTransitions">
<p class="ng-binding" ng-click="selectTransition(Transition)">Draft</p>
</div>
<div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="Transition in DirectTransitions">
<p class="ng-binding" ng-click="selectTransition(Transition)">Approved</p>
</div>
<div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="Transition in DirectTransitions">
<p class="ng-binding" ng-click="selectTransition(Transition)">Posted</p>
</div>
```

I can click on each link individually like this:

```
it('should select Draft', function() {
   element.all(by.repeater('Transition in DirectTransitions'));.filter(function(elem) {
    return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
      return text === 'Draft';
    });
  }).click();
  });
```

Which I am currently doing, but if the text changes or another link is added/removed to the page. I have to go back and refactor again to add/remove the link or change the text which I am trying to avoid.

I was able to get the link names doing something like this.

```
it('should get link names', function() {
  element.all(by.repeater('<locator>')).map(function(item) {
  return item.getText();
  }).then(function(labels) {
  expect(labels).toEqual(['one', 'two', 'three']);
  });
 });
```

But haven't been able to figure out how to iterate over each link and click on each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over every link with [`each()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each):

```
var links = element.all(by.repeater('Transition in DirectTransitions'));
links.each(function (link) {
    link.click();
});
expect(links.getText()).toEqual(['one', 'two', 'three']);
```

Depending on what happens on click, you may get "stale element reference" errors (see comments for follow-up threads with several ways to approach that).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try :)

Comment: That did click the first element, which took me to the next page as I expected. I then had to nav back to the page with the initial links which it did, but instead of selecting the next link I get an error    "Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Comment: @DennisFerguson ah, this means that the page changes after the first click. Here is a relevant thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29823757/771848. Also, you may keep track of a current index of a link, sample (not in js/protractor): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448091/how-to-fetch-all-links-and-click-those-links-one-by-one-using-selenium-webdriver. Hope that helps.